# How to compute VRM output limit

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

Three different B450 motherboards have an output stage supporting 40 amps (6 phase), 50 amps (4 phase), and 60 amps (6 phase).

I would like to understand the relationship between input to VRM (assume +12v DC at 40 amps) to the current limit deliverable to the CPU.

How many amps could be delivered @ 1.4 volts to a CPU?

Comment: Product links? Data sheets? Fix the contradiction in your first sentence?

Comment: Assuming that the DCDC converters / VRM (which convert 12 V to 1.4 V) are 100% efficient (they're not but let's assume) then the **power** going into the DCDC converter is **equal** to the power that is coming out of the DCDC converters. With a more realistic efficiency of for example 90%, the power delivered at the output drops to 90% (10% is lost as heat in the DCDC) of of what you calculated for 100% efficiency.

Comment: I am satisfied with Bimpelrekkie comment as an answer to my question. Thanks